# Map induced by a polynomial map between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am rather stuck on a (probably quite basic) problem in introductory algebraic geometry.

Suppose $\varphi: V\longrightarrow W$ is a polynomial map between two varieties $V\subset {\mathbb A}^n$ and $W\subset {\mathbb A}^m$, where ${\mathbb A}^n$ is $n$ dimensional affine space over an algebraically closed field $k$. So there are polynomials $T_1,\ldots,T_m$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $\varphi(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(T_1(a_1,\ldots,a_n),\ldots,T_m(a_1,\ldots,a_n))$, and we define 
$T=(T_1,\ldots,T_m)$, so that we get a map $\hat{T}:k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]\longrightarrow k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ by composition, $\hat{T}(G)=G\circ T$. 
Suppose that $I$ is the ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ defining $V$ and $J$ is the ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ defining $W$. Then we have a naturally induced ring homomorphism $\hat{\varphi}: \Gamma(W) \longrightarrow
\Gamma(V)$ between the coordinate rings $\Gamma(V)=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ and $\Gamma(W) = k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/J$, defined by $\hat{\varphi}(G+J)=G\circ T+I$.

I can easily prove that if $\varphi$ is surjective, then 
$\hat{\varphi}$ is injective.

But I am stuck on the problem of deciding if $\varphi$ injective will 
imply that $\hat{\varphi}$ is surjective. I do not have sufficient intuition in this area, and the simple examples I could construct (such as taking $\varphi$ to be the embedding $a\mapsto (a,0)$) seem to say that $\hat{\varphi}$ will be surjective, but when trying to prove it in general I do not see how to do it.

Comment: In my original post I made the incorrect statement (now deleted) that I could prove that $\hat{\varphi}$ is surjective if $\varphi$ is bijective. After some more reading, I found out that there is a theorem that says that $\hat{\varphi}$ will be surjective only when $\varphi$ has a left polynomial inverse (in which case it is easy to prove surjectivity of $\hat{\varphi}$ ). So there was no hope of proving surjectivity of $\hat{\varphi}$ just from the injectivity of $\varphi$.

Comment: The surjectivity of $\hat{\phi}$ is equivalent to $\phi$ being a closed embedding, i.e. an isomorphism of $V$ onto its image in $W$. To see that $\phi$ bijective is not enough: consider $k[t^2, t^3] \to k[t]$, which is not surjective, in particular not an isomorphism. But on points, $V \to W$ is just "pinching" the origin on $\mathbb{P}^1$, introducing a cusp. So $V \to W$ is bijective topologically.

Comment: Followup: surjectivity of $\phi$ is equivalent to the ring map $\hat{\phi}$ having the lying-over property.

Comment: @JakeLevinson thanks, could you give me a reference for the meaning of "a ring map has the lying-over property"? I found the meaning for ring extensions but not for maps.

Comment: Maybe it’s not in widespread usage, I just mean $f : R \to S$ such that for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$, there exists a prime ideal $Q$ of $S$ such that $f^{-1}(Q) = P$. This specializes to the Lying-Over property when $f$ is injective, but it’s nothing deep, basically just unwinding what surjectivity means on Spec.